# Formulário de Contacto

Tags: php, html

Tenho este código para verificar se é um valor numérico e já tentei que o valor máximo de dígitos fossem 9. Tentei também com != ou ==

**O que tentei:**

Opção 1

```
    //php verif phone
if(isset($_POST["phone"])){
   if (strlen($phone) != 9) {   
    if (!$phone) {
        $errors[] = "Indique um número válido.";
    }elseif ( !is_numeric( $phone )) {
        $errors[]= "Verifique novamente o número.";
    }
}
```

Opção 2

```
    //php verif phone
if(isset($_POST["phone"]) != 9){    
    if (!$phone) {
        $errors[] = "Indique um número válido.";
    }elseif ( !is_numeric( $phone )) {
        $errors[]= "Verifique novamente o número.";
    }
}
```

Opção 3

```
    //php verif phone
if(isset($_POST["phone"])){ 
    if (!$phone) {
        $errors[] = "Indique um número válido.";
    }elseif ( !is_numeric( $phone ) != 9) {
        $errors[]= "Verifique novamente o número.";
    }
}
```

Andei à procura aqui e via google e supostamente pelo que li deveria dar. Mas até agora obriga-me a ter 10 dígitos, e não 9 como é o meu objectivo.

```
<label for="phone"></label>
<input name="phone" type="tel" id="phone" size="9"
   value="" placeholder="Telemóvel"
   class="required digits" title="Verifique novamente o número.">
```

Comment: O que acontence que o código não funciona, de um exemplo da entrada, tbm, se o telefone for formatado não será interpretado como número.

Comment: Esse campo obriga-me a ter 10 dígitos, caso contrário indica-me para verificar o número.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso em JQuery ou Javascript puro. Mas é uma ótima prática você sempre validar os inputs no seu sistema.
Então sempre valide no PHP, mesmo que tenha sido validado no Front-end antes.
Para validar se você tem um tipo numérico você pode usar a função is_numeric que retorna um booleano.

```
<?php
    if(is_numeric($phone)){}
?>
```

Para saber a quantidade de caracteres você pode usar esse código abaixo:

```
<?php
    if (function_exists('mb_strlen'))
    {
        return mb_strlen($phone);
    }
    return strlen($phone);
?>
```

No fluxo geral poderia ser assim:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
    if(!is_numeric($phone))
        return false;

    if (function_exists('mb_strlen'))
    {
        return mb_strlen($phone) < 9;
    }

    return strlen($phone) < 9;

}
?>
```

Links de documentação:

http://php.net/is_numeric 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php 
http://www.php.net/isset

Comment: Obrigada pela dica. Tenho de aprofundar mais o meu conhecimento em PHP. No entanto o cliente quer acrescentar o 00351 ao número por isso ficou resolvido. Apenas com 9 dígitos não estava a dar.

Answer (score 1):

Eu removeria os caracteres que não são inteiros antes de fazer essa verificação.  Um exemplo:

```
<?php

$phone = isset( $_POST["phone"] ) ? $_POST["phone"] : null;

function verificaDigitosTelefone( $telefone , $permitido = 9)
{
    return ( strlen( preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '' , $telefone ) ) == $permitido );
}


if( empty($phone) || !verificaDigitosTelefone($phone) )
{
    echo 'Telefone inválido';
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

utilize menor e não diferente, diferente pode ser maior ou menor.

```
 if (strlen($phone) < 9){
    echo 'informe um numero de 9 digitos';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim

```
if(strlen($_POST["phone"])==9 && is_numeric($_POST["phone"])){
  echo 'Número valido';
}else{
  echo 'Número inválido';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução simples de tres linhas utilizando operador ternário seria:

```
$phone = (isset($_POST['phone'])) ? (is_numeric($_POST['phone'] && strlen($_POST['phone']) >= 9) ? $_POST['phone'] : "";
if ($phone == "")
  echo "Número inválido.";
```

Answer (score 0):

O código abaixo deve atender o que você precisa

```
$phone ="912341234";
$phone = isset($phone[8]) && is_numeric($phone) ? $phone : null;
if ($phone ===null ){
  echo "invalido";
 } else{
   echo "valido";
 }
```

Vale a pena ler 
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ctype-digit.php

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou fazer essa verificação no formulário, antes de dar o POST?
Você poderia definir uma máscara com javascript da forma que você deseja que o usuário informe o número.

http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/